# PHP's preg_replace() causing Segmentation Fault 11 due to group capture

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

```
preg_replace('/(\s|\-|\||\.|\,){2,}/', ' ', $contents)
```

Causes Segmentation Fault while parsing some of the strings probably due to exhausting the PCRE recursion limit defined in the php.ini

I modified the regexp to use a non-capturing group, however, I still get a Segmentation Fault 11 for the same content.
Modified RegExp:

```
preg_replace('/(?:\s|\-|\||\.|\,){2,}/', ' ', $contents)
```

Finally, I changed my RegExp to (without using any grouping):

```
preg_replace('/[\s-|.,]{2,}/', ' ', $contents)
```

And this does not cause the segmentaion fault.

I have the following queries from these observations :

1. Is the final regexp replacing the content as the initial one was?
2. Why while using a non-capturing group does not solve the Segmentation Fault error?

Comment: It is hard to tell without input strings and desired output.

Comment: One clear difference i spot the usage of ``-`` character inside your last regex ``/[\s-|.,]{2,}/`` s/b ``/[-\s|.,]{2,}/`` or ``/[\s|.,-]{2,}/``...since ``-`` is meta-character inside of a class, i.e., ``[...]``

Comment: @Cylian I don't think that should create a difference. Is it not just matching occurrences of any character mentioned in [ ] ?

Comment: @Jan, and what do you think about the Query 1? Do they match the same results?

Comment: @Cylian got it what you meant. Could /[\s\-|.,]{2,}/ be a possibility ?